# npm-bundle doesnt work behind firewall but works fine in personal laptop

Tags: node.js, aws-device-farm

When I try to bundle the node test suite project using npm-bundle for devicefarm Appium Node Run,
it is creating .npmbndle folder at the root of the project and an empty node_modules folder.
It works just fine in personal laptop, attached screenshot of logs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading these logs correctly, then they're saying that npm-bundle cannot find your package.json file, which is essential for telling it which packages to bundle. Can you confirm if this file is in the local directory in which you're bundling? If so, can you post your full logs pasted as text here?

Thank you,
Jon